# Generating a random password in python using tkinter UI

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, tkinter

so I followed a tutorial using tkinter and python to make a password generator.
I followed the tutorial and it worked, but I wanted to expand on it.
It all began when I wanted a "Copy to clipboard button" to let the user copy the password. But it always gave not a string but <function [name of function] at 0x.....>
Now that part works but for some reason the password generation is broken now.
Any help appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import string

##### PASSWORD GENERATOR BY ROMAN ROTH

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x280")
root.title("Password Generator")

##### INITIAL VARIABLES
title = StringVar()
choice = IntVar()
lengthlabel = StringVar()
passlength = IntVar()
symbols = "!§$%&/()=?{[]}*+'#~,;.:-_'<>"
poor = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase
average = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
advanced = poor + average + symbols


##### FUNCTIONS
def selection():
    choice.get()


def callback():
    Isum.config(text=passgen())


Isum = Label(root, text="")
Isum.pack(side=BOTTOM)

password = str(callback)


# Password generation script - joins a random symbol to the string for how many times set in the spinbox
def passgen():
    global password
    password = ""
    if choice.get() == 1:
        return password.join(random.sample(poor, passlength.get()))
    elif choice.get() == 2:
        return password.join(random.sample(average, passlength.get()))
    elif choice.get() == 3:
        return password.join(random.sample(advanced, passlength.get()))


# Copies the current password to the clipboard
def copytoclipboard():
    global password
    print(password)
    Isum.clipboard_clear()
    Isum.clipboard_append(password)
    Isum.update()


##### USER INTERFACE
label = Label(root, textvariable=title).pack()
title.set("The strength of the password:")

R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Uppercase and Lowercase", variable=choice, value=1, command=selection).pack(anchor=CENTER)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Uppercase, Lowercase, Digits", variable=choice, value=2, command=selection).pack(
    anchor=CENTER)
R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Uppercase, Lowercase, Digits, Symbols", variable=choice, value=3, command=selection).pack(
    anchor=CENTER)

lengthlabel.set("Password length: (8 to 24)")
lengthtitle = Label(root, textvariable=lengthlabel).pack()

spinboxlength = Spinbox(root, from_=8, to_=24, textvariable=passlength, width=13).pack()

passgenButton = Button(root, text="Generate Password", command=callback)
passgenButton.pack()

copyButton = Button(root, text="Copy Password to Clipboard", command=copytoclipboard)
copyButton.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you elaborate more ?

Comment: `passgenButton = Button(root, text="Generate Password", command=passgen())` try chaning to `passgenButton = Button(root, text="Generate Password", command=passgen)` removing the brackets of the command

Comment: I removed the brackets but it did not fix my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make the password variable accessible to both functions.

```
passgen()
copytoclipboard()
```

since it is shared between them.

one of the ways to solve this is to make the `password` variable global like this:

```
# Password generation script - joins a random symbol to the string for how many times set in the spinbox
def passgen():
    global password
    password = ""
    if choice.get() == 1:
        password = password.join(random.sample(poor, passlength.get()))
    elif choice.get() == 2:
        password = password.join(random.sample(average, passlength.get()))
    elif choice.get() == 3:
        password = password.join(random.sample(advanced, passlength.get()))
```

```
# Copies the current password to the clipboard
def copytoclipboard():
    global password
    print(password)
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(password)
    root.update()
```

it should work now.

full code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import string

##### PASSWORD GENERATOR

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x280")
root.title("Password Generator")

##### INITIAL VARIABLES
title = StringVar()
choice = IntVar()
lengthlabel = StringVar()
passlength = IntVar()
symbols = "!§$%&/()=?{[]}*+'#~,;.:-_'<>"
poor = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase
average = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
advanced = poor + average + symbols
password = "test"


##### FUNCTIONS
def selection():
    choice.get()


# Password generation script - joins a random symbol to the string for how many times set in the spinbox
def passgen():
    global password
    password = ""
    if choice.get() == 1:
        password = password.join(random.sample(poor, passlength.get()))
    elif choice.get() == 2:
        password = password.join(random.sample(average, passlength.get()))
    elif choice.get() == 3:
        password = password.join(random.sample(advanced, passlength.get()))



# passtext = passgen()


# Copies the current password to the clipboard
def copytoclipboard():
    global password
    print(password)
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(password)
    root.update()


##### USER INTERFACE
label = Label(root, textvariable=title).pack()
title.set("The strength of the password:")

R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Uppercase and Lowercase", variable=choice, value=1, command=selection).pack(anchor=CENTER)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Uppercase, Lowercase, Digits", variable=choice, value=2, command=selection).pack(
    anchor=CENTER)
R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Uppercase, Lowercase, Digits, Symbols", variable=choice, value=3, command=selection).pack(
    anchor=CENTER)

lengthlabel.set("Password length: (8 to 24)")
lengthtitle = Label(root, textvariable=lengthlabel).pack()

spinboxlength = Spinbox(root, from_=8, to_=24, textvariable=passlength, width=13).pack()

passgenButton = Button(root, text="Generate Password", command=passgen)
passgenButton.pack()

passwordlabel = Label(root, text=password).pack(side=BOTTOM)

copyButton = Button(root, text="Copy Password to Clipboard", command=copytoclipboard)
copyButton.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

to fix the test label add:

```
view_pass = StringVar()


def passgen():
    global password
    password = ""
    if choice.get() == 1:
        password = password.join(random.sample(poor, passlength.get()))
    elif choice.get() == 2:
        password = password.join(random.sample(average, passlength.get()))
    elif choice.get() == 3:
        password = password.join(random.sample(advanced, passlength.get()))
    view_pass.set(password)
```

and change:

```
passwordlabel = Label(root, text=password).pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

to

```
passwordlabel = Label(root, textvariable=view_pass).pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

because it is a variable and not a static text

Comment: I added the callback function from the tutorial back to the code (it used Isum and I did not know why it didnt work without it but now my password gets generated like normal again. However the output of the "copy to clipboard button is still nothing after adding your suggestion to make the variable global.
I posted the updated code above.

Comment: @RomanRoth I do know exactly what is Isum, but if you put the above code I posted and the command = passgen in the button event then it should work fine, I have tested it. I have added the full code for your reference.

Comment: Thank you now the copy to clipboard works - however below the copy button there is just test. With the Isum function it displayed the password - could you show me how to add that in as well?

Comment: @RomanRoth you are welcome, I have added the requested function to the above post, check it out.

Comment: You are great thank you so much - after 3 days it now finally works as intended!